# Selenium interrupt Explicit Wait

Tags: java, selenium

I have a thread which execute commands like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitSecs);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xPath))).click();
```

Sometimes I want to stop thread before to finish execution. But if thread wait for my Element, it will stop only after time expire(TimeoutException) or command is executed.

There is a way to stop Explicit Wait? Like `Thread.interrupted()` with `Thread.sleep()`. Even if throw an exception.

Comment: `Explicit Wait` is configured by the end user, if you want to stop at 5 secs why not to configure `waitSecs` as **5 seconds**?

Comment: Because I want to stop the entire program. That does not depend by what happens in execution. I have an interface with two buttons, start and stop. When I press stop, I want to stop it imediatelly not to wait for explicit wait.

Comment: At which condition do you want to `stop the entire program`? Possibly your program is single-threaded and you can't `exit` while waiter is in execution.

Comment: [CODE](https://i.imgur.com/PMkAmyn.jpg) - MyMethod is started from another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and my decision was to write my own waiting function, that will try to find the element, if no elements, will wait for 0,5 seconds and will  try again.
This helped me to stop my code whenever I want.

Comment: This is not ideal for me. I already have my custom methods imported as jar. But remain as a good idea.